# MySQL - Exclude row if no row exists from LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, database

I have an SQL query which is working ok to an extent.

The LEFT OUTER JOINs work ok, but if there is no record in mdl_modules OR mdl_resource it comes up with NULL.

How can I exclude the records from mdl_course_modules WHERE there is no record in either of the LEFT OUTER JOINs?

I presume i would use ISNULL() but not sure on the correct syntax to incorporate with my query.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", "cm.id AS theid, m.name AS mname, r.name AS resourcename, r.summary AS resourcesummary,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(cm.added, '%D %M %Y') AS dateadded")."
        FROM mdl_course_modules cm 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN mdl_modules m on cm.module = m.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN mdl_resource r on cm.instance = r.id
        WHERE m.name = 'resource' AND cm.visible = 1
        $scourse
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
```

Comment: Use an inner, not an outer join.  Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. To be honest I have never looked into SQL joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this would be accomplished by switching to an `INNER JOIN`, but [`INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) in MySql is equivalent to a `CROSS JOIN` so that won't help practically.

To solve the issue, add the desired `WHERE` condition, using `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM_UNIXTIME(cm.added, '%D %M %Y') AS dateadded")."
    FROM mdl_course_modules cm 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mdl_modules m on cm.module = m.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mdl_resource r on cm.instance = r.id
    WHERE m.name = 'resource' AND cm.visible = 1
        && (!ISNULL(m.name) || !ISNULL(r.name))
```

Comment: In what way is an `INNER JOIN` (still specifying a join condition) any more equivalent to a `CROSS JOIN` in MySQL than any other RDBMS?

Comment: @eggyal: *"In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent."*

Comment: Wow. An INNER JOIN is something **completely** different than a CROSS JOIN - what where those developers smoking?

Answer (score 1):

WHERE m.name = 'resource' AND cm.visible=1 AND (m.id IS NOT NULL OR r.id IS NOT NULL)